# Change the colour of windows taskbar, C#

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, taskbar, appearance

In my simple WPF Application I want to change the colour of the users windows taskbar when a button is clicked. The taskbar I'm refering to is the bottom bar in windows where the start menu, clock, etc, is.

I tried solving this by creating a new window, when the button is clicked, with transparent background but I could not position it over the taskbar and make it unclickable.

Comment: why you want to do this while you can easily do that by personalizing your theme on Windows?

Comment: The application is going to be running in the background and change to different colours during a timer.

Comment: It's not clear on how exactly you want it to look. If you want to change the underlying background color (layering under the icon) and keep the hover effect, then it's not really easy. If it's just for indication purpose, I suggest to attach a simple signing symbol (such as a bold bottom border...) on the button. Then you can use the `Window.TaskbarItemInfo` to specify it via the `Overlay` property (accepts an `ImageSource`).